# No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'vector<bitset<8>>' c++

Tags: c++, vector, hex, bitset

I keep getting the error:

```
No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'vector<bitset<8>>'
```

I am trying to execute something while this hex value is not contained within my vector. I guess the error has something to do with the way I am trying to check for an element. If anyone could tell me how to do a properly check a vector for a defined constant that would be great. Here is my basic code:

```
using namespace std;

//Variables I am trying to compare 
#define HALT_OPCODE 0x19;
vector<bitset<8> > memory(65536);
bitset<16> PC = 0;

 int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
 {

    //Error Occurs here
    while(memory[PC] != HALT_OPCODE){
        fetchNextInstruction();
        executeInstruction();


    }

   return 0;

 }
```

Comment: [`std::vector::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)

Comment: `std::vector::operator[]` takes an argument of type `std::vector::size_type` as it's argument. you're trying to pass it a `std::bitset`. Of course it won't work.

Comment: Use `std::find` to look for a value inside the vector

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ulong

Comment: You're going to have to explain what your code is _supposed_ to do because, by your own admission, it does not do that thing. Therefore we cannot tell what it is supposed to do instead by simply reading it. Basic logic that I would expect a computer programmer to know. :/

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any sense in this construction

```
while(memory[PC] != HALT_OPCODE){
    cout << "Do Something";
```

but in any case you have to write

```
while(memory[PC.to_ulong()].to_ulong() != HALT_OPCODE){
    cout << "Do Something";
```

Or

```
while(memory[PC.to_ulong()] != HALT_OPCODE){
    cout << "Do Something";
```

because there is a non-explicit conversion constructor in the class std::bitset.

Comment: I made some edits to my code. My program will keep running as long as it does not receive an Opcode which cause its termination. Also I keep getting errors with your solutions: It keeps stating: Expected Expression ')' but I don't see where parenthesis are missing.

Comment: @dave As I said your code makes no sense. I only showed how to write it syntaxically correctly.